# Formal Languages : Grammar, construct a grammar which produces a particular pattern

Tags: computer-science, grammar, formal-languages

I have to construction an L(G) which creates the following pattern:

"The word starts always with a 'b', if an a is in the word, that is immediately followed by 'b'"

So we cannot have two 'a' consequently

```
For ex the pattern can be:  'b', 'bb', 'bab', 'bbbbbbab', 'bababab'
```

I construct the Finite State Machine, but I am not able to find a general L(G) which produces this kind of grammar, this is what I got so far:

```
L(G) = { b^n  a^m b^k | n>1, a => 0, b > 1 }
```

Does anybody has an idea how to proceed with this problem, if yes please tell me what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The language is this:

> All strings of a's and b's which start with at least one b and which have at least one b after any a.

Whenever you're trying to understand a language, I recommend thinking about the shortest strings in the language and how longer strings are built up. The shortest string in the language described above is b. If we have a string in the language, how can we get longer strings? Well, we can always add more b's to get a string in the language. If we add an a, we must add at least one b. This suggests a regular expression of the form:

```
  bb* means one b, then any number of additional b's
  ^       this Kleene star lets us add any number of a's, or none at all
  |       ^
  |       |
bb* (abb*)*
|-| |-----|
 |     |
 |     V
 V     after any a, we must have at least one b
 the string must start with at least one b
```

To get a grammar, we can use our observations of the shortest string and steps for deriving longer ones to write a recursive definition:

- b is in L (*the shortest string is the base case*)
- if x is in L, xb is in L (*we can always add a b*)
- if x is in L, xab is in L (*we can add an a if we follow it with a b*)
- nothing else is in L (*boilerplate for recursive definitions*)

To go from a recursive definition to a grammar, add a production to derive the base case from the start symbol:

```
S -> b
```

`S`, by definition, derives a string in our language. In particular, from the other two productive rules above, we know that we can add one b or both an a and a b to the end of anything `S` derives, so we add productions

```
S -> Sb
S -> Sab
```

Putting it all together, we get:

```
S -> b
S -> Sb
S -> Sab
```

Another, maybe better, way to get a grammar is to find an automaton that gives you your language, and then use a construction to get the grammar. We might recognize this language is regular and write down a DFA for it:

```
      _               _
     / \             / \
  b |  |        a,b |  |
     \ V             \ V
----->q0----->q1----->q2
       ^  a   |   a
       |      |
       \______/
          b
```

Here, `q0` is the initial and only accepting state, `q1` is the state where you have seen an `a` but not the required `b`, and `q2` is a dead state reached after seeing two `a`s in a row. To write down the grammar, you write down the transitions as follows:

```
(q0) -> b(q0)
(q0) -> a(q1)
(q1) -> b(q0)
(q1) -> a(q2)
(q2) -> b(q2)
(q2) -> a(q2)
```

Finally, add empty/epsilon/lambda productions for every nonterminal representing an accepting state:

```
(q0) -> e
```

Put it together and you have a grammar:

```
(q0) -> b(q0)
(q0) -> a(q1)
(q1) -> b(q0)
(q1) -> a(q2)
(q2) -> b(q2)
(q2) -> a(q2)
(q0) -> e
```

You can remove empty/epsilon/lambda transitions from this and empty states to put it into Chomsky normal form (or whatever, close to it, I forget the order terminals and nonterminals need to be in):

```
(q0) -> a(q1)
(q0) -> b(q0) | b
(q1) -> b(q0) | b
```

This is the same as our grammar before, except it adds an extra nonterminal whose only responsibility is putting the required b after an a, whereas the other grammar does it in one production.

Comment: I think the question was to define language, not grammar or automaton generating it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write the definition like this:

L = {b<sup>n</sup>(a<sup>x</sup>b<sup>y</sup>)<sup>m</sup> | n>0, m>=0, x in {0,1}, y>=x}